# Launching popup on left overlay panel in jquery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I'm working on mobile app. I Have a panel and a popup, i want popup to launch on left overlay panel when clicked on signout . I'm not gettin where i'm going worng. Please someone suggest. Thanks in advance. Below is my code.

```
  <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="demo-page" class="my-page">
  <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-position-fixed="true"  >
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="absolute" >
  <h1>settin</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
  <div class="content-primary">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false" data-theme="a" data-dividertheme="a" >
  <li><a href="#signout" rel="external"><img src="images/signout.png" alt="Documents" class="ui-li-icon">Sign out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--/content-primary --> 
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="popup" id="signout" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all"> <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
  <form>
  <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
    <h3 style="color:#29a797;"> Window</h3>
    <label for="un" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="user" id="un" value="" placeholder="username" data-theme="a">
     <button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check">Sign in</button>
    </div>
    </form>
   </div>
   <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
   <h1>Panel</h1>
   <a href="#mypanel" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slideup" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" >Bars</a> </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not referring to popup and using incorrect `rel` attribute.

```
<a href="#signout" rel="external">
```

You should change it to

```
<a href="#signout" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="origin">
```

`data-rel="popup"` means the target hash is a popup and `data-position-to="origin"` to position the popup on the top of referral button.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lppua2p7/)**

Comment: @ Omar, I have another issue which i'm gettin after i changed popup footer to this---- 
<div data-role="footer" data-id="fixedFooter"  >
     <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:48%; padding-left:3.5%;"><a href="index.html" rel="external"><button  data-theme="a" >Log Out</button> </a></div>    
 <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:48%; padding-left:2%;"><button data-theme="a" >Cancel</button></div>

</fieldset>
</div>
The issue is if i click on submit button it says "error loading page" infact i have not linked anything to buttons.Please suggest

Comment: @neeraj you're liniking to index.html.

Comment: even after removing link (a href="index.html" rel="external"). I'm getting error "error loading page".

Comment: @neeraj use `a` instead of `button` and try again.

Comment: @ Omar , if i'm using "a" instead of "button". Button alignment is going for toss.

Answer (score 0):

yes. for each element in jqm you should set data-rel. Withot it the button can not execut element and run it. for example if you want to set button for back action, you should set data-rel="back" for button.